# High interprocess timing variations, but low intraprocess timing variations for the same task

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

I am running this code (full code here: http://codepad.org/5OJBLqIA) to time repeated daxpy function calls with and without flushing the operands from cache beforehand:

```
#define KB 1024

int main()
{
    int cache_size = 32*KB;
    double alpha = 42.5;

    int operand_size = cache_size/(sizeof(double)*2);
    double* X = new double[operand_size];
    double* Y = new double[operand_size];


    //95% confidence interval
    double max_risk = 0.05;
    //Interval half width
    double w;
    int n_iterations = 50000;
    students_t dist(n_iterations-1);
    double T = boost::math::quantile(complement(dist,max_risk/2));
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean,tag::variance> > unflushed_acc;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; ++i)
    {
        fill(X,operand_size);
        fill(Y,operand_size);
        double seconds = wall_time();
        daxpy(alpha,X,Y,operand_size);
        seconds = wall_time() - seconds;
        unflushed_acc(seconds);
    }

    w = T*sqrt(variance(unflushed_acc))/sqrt(count(unflushed_acc));
    printf("Without flush: time=%g +/- %g ns\n",mean(unflushed_acc)*1e9,w*1e9);

    //Using clflush instruction
    //We need to put the operands back in cache
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean,tag::variance> > clflush_acc;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; ++i)
    {
        fill(X,operand_size);
        fill(Y,operand_size);

        flush_array(X,operand_size);
        flush_array(Y,operand_size);
        double seconds = wall_time();
        daxpy(alpha,X,Y,operand_size);
        seconds = wall_time() - seconds;
        clflush_acc(seconds);
    }

    w = T*sqrt(variance(clflush_acc))/sqrt(count(clflush_acc));
    printf("With clflush: time=%g +/- %g ns\n",mean(clflush_acc)*1e9,w*1e9);

    return 0;
}
```

This code measures the rate and the uncertainty averaged over the given number of iterations. Averaging over lots of iterations successfully minimizes the variance caused by contention for memory access from various cores (discussed in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777598/very-high-uncertainty-in-timings-after-cache-flush)), but the average value thus obtained varies by a **huge** amount between separate invocations of the same executable:

```
$ ./variance
Without flush: time=3107.76 +/- 0.268198 ns
With clflush: time=5862.33 +/- 9.84313 ns
$ ./variance
Without flush: time=3105.71 +/- 0.237823 ns
With clflush: time=7802.66 +/- 12.3163 ns
```

These were run immediately after one another. Why do the timings for the flushed case (but not the unflushed case) vary so much between processes, but so little within a given process?

**Appendix**

Code is run on Mac OS X 10.8 on an Intel Xeon 5650.

Comment: Have you retried the experiment? Does this behavior always exhibit itself? Have you tried `callgrind`?

Comment: @Shahbaz, trying it several times, it tends to cluster around 7000, but it's jumped down near 6000 and up to 7300. Regarding callgrind, something about the boost code makes it crash in callgrind...